# If a field $K$ (of characteristic 0) has no proper extensions of the form $K[\sqrt[n]{x}]$, is it algebraically closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, radicals

Let $K$ be a field, assume characteristic 0 if this simplifies things. Suppose we know that for any positive integer $n$ and any $x \in K$ the polynomial $X^n - x$ has a root in $K$. Is $K$ algebraically closed?

Working on the assumption that the answer is probably "no", how would one construct a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer in characteristic $0$ is no. For instance, the "root closure"* of $\Bbb Q$ still wouldn't let you solve, say, an unsolvable quintic like $x^5-x-1 = 0$, because we know its solutions can't be written using roots in $\Bbb Q$, so it can't be written using roots in the root closure either.

*What I mean by "root closure" is this: Start with $\Bbb Q$, and consider it a subfield of $\Bbb C$ (or of $\overline{\Bbb Q}$). To $\Bbb Q$, add all $n$th roots of all elements of $\Bbb Q$. Then add all $n$'th roots of all elements in that new field, and so on. The root closure is the final result, i.e. the union of these fields. Any element in that field may be written with a finite expression involving only addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, roots and rational numbers.

Answer (score 4):

In positive characteristic the situation is even worse. For instance, the field $K$ with two elements trivially satisfies your property, but the polynomial $x^{2} + x + 1$ has no roots in $K$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's what happens when I only read titles. I need to stop doing that.

Comment: Part of the conversation is gone, but I suppose it is related to the fact that the title appears to restrict the question to characteristic $0$, whereas in the question body it is only stated *assume characteristic $0$ if this simplifies things.*

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks. And a Happy New Year to you!

Comment: Thank you, you too!!!